# Laravel 8 + backpack throws error on "php artisan backpack:crud User"

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-backpack, laravel-backpack-5

I installed a fresh install or laravel "^8.75" and backpack "^5.3" and when I run "php artisan backpack:crud User" I get this error:

```
BadMethodCallException 
Method Illuminate\Support\Stringable::lcfirst does not exist.
```

Does anyone know what the issue might be ? I cannot find a solution online.

Comment: can you please provide a full stack trace?

Comment: @BhaumikPandhi Yes, of course https://pastebin.com/5mgWmAEz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just submitted the PR to fix this, we are using lcfirst as part of Laravel Str::class and that's not available in L9, so the error raises.

It should be fixed, merged and tagged during today.

You can follow the PR here: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/Generators/pull/149

Cheers

Comment: Done, merged and tagged!